# Escaping # char in URL RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Good afternoon!

I am creating a rewrite rule that will forwards the example1.tv domain my client purchased to URL generated by one of our vendors at https://www.example2.tv/SiteName#broadcasts

The problem that I am having is that, even with the # char escaped, the URL rewrites to https:// www.example2.tv/PageName%23broadcasts which results in a 404.  I've changed the URLs for confidentiality's sake, but here is the rewrite rule as I've written in the .htaccess file.  Any help would be appreciated!

---

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(www.)?(example1).tv [nc] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.tv/PageName#broadcasts [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1\.tv$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example2.tv/PageName#broadcasts [R=301,L,NE]
```

`NE` (no encode) flag makes sure to send `#` literally to clients.

Comment: @gosaultech if someone answers our questions we accept them.